# Compare files by position

Tags: bash, diff

I want to compare two files only by their first column.

My first looks like this:

```
0009608a4138a8e7 hdisk26 altinst_rootvg
000f7d4a8234a675 hdisk12 vgdbf
000f7d4a8234d5c9 hdisk22 vgarcbkp
```

My second file looks like this:

```
000f7d4a8234a675 hdiskpower64 [Lun_vgdbf]
000f7d4a8234d5c9 hdiskpower61 [Lun_vgarcbkp]
```

This is the output I would like to generate:

```
0009608a4138a8e7 hdisk26 altinst_rootvg
000f7d4a8234a675 hdisk12 vgdbf hdiskpower64 [Lun_vgdbf]
000f7d4a8234d5c9 hdisk22 vgarcbkp hdiskpower61 [Lun_vgarcbkp]
```

I wonder why `diff` does not support positional compare.
Something like `diff -y -p1-17 file1 file2`. Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "column"? I can see only plain text in your files. And what did you do to get "the output"?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I reformatted your question so that it is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` to produce your desired output :

```
join -a 1 file1 file2
```

The `-a 1` option states to output lines from the first file which have no correspondances in the second, so this assumes the first file contains every id that is present in the second.

It also relies on the files being sorted on their first file, which could be the case according to your sample data. If it's not you will need to sort them beforehand (the `join` command will warn you about your files not being sorted).

Sample execution :

```
$ echo '1 a b
> 2 c d
> 3 e f' > test1

$ echo '2 9 8
> 3 7 6' > test2

$ join -a 1 test1 test2
1 a b
2 c d 9 8
3 e f 7 6
```

[Ideone test with your sample data](https://ideone.com/Nok8Fq).